# windows script to detect and fix if the network adapter needs resetting

Tags: scripting, windows-7, networking

all,

is there any script that I can put on a scheduler to auto reset adapter only if there is a network connection failure?

I am running Windows 7

-Jeremy

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Powershell script for doing this, replace n.n.n.n with your Default Gateway IP address and Name of connection with the name of your connection!

```
$pingtest = test-connection n.n.n.n -count 1 -quiet

if(!$pingtest)
{
 $nic = gwmi win32_networkadapter -filter "NetConnectionID='Name of connection'"
  $nic.disable()
  sleep 5
  $nic.enable()
}
```

Save this as filename.ps1 (for example) and create a Windows scheduled task with the following command:

Powershell.exe c:\pathtoscript\filename.ps1 -noprofile -Noninteractive

If you haven't used powershell before then start it up and run the following command to ensure your scheduled script will run:

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

More on this here: [Powershell Execution Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to check any IP 192.168.1.187 and if it fails it will reset the network adaptor "Ethernet 2" (which is shown when I perform an IP Config). I consider this to be practically the same use case as described in the question at the top of this page.
I propose the following solution, which I hope works on Win10, though I am not sure about that.

```
$pingtest = test-connection 192.168.1.187 -count 1 -quiet

if(!$pingtest)
{
 $nic = gwmi win32_networkadapter -filter "NetConnectionID='Ethernet 2'"
  $nic.disable()
  sleep 5
  $nic.enable()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not entirely clear to me whether this is an answer or a new question. If it is an answer, please [edit] it for clarity, otherwise you can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I edited to turn this into an answer, in the only way I can see that you might have meant it to be an answer. If I am wrong, this was flaggable as "not an answer" and you should delete it.